# How to make our bot can lockdown a channel for 5 sec then unlock, to prevent spam

Tags: javascript, discord.js

Hello I want my bot to lockdown the channel if he detect something includes "everyone got" then he'll gonna lockdown the channel for 5 sec and send an embed message

Here's my code

```
client.on("message", (eventnpc) => {
    if (!eventnpc.embeds[0]) return;
    if (!eventnpc.embeds[0].fields[0]) return;
    let entVa = eventnpc.embeds[0].fields[0].value;
    let entNa = eventnpc.embeds[0].fields[0].name;
    if (entNa.includes("Everyone got")) {
      const bapak = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('THE EVENT IS OVER!')
      .setImage('https://media.giphy.com/media/l4Ki2obCyAQS5WhFe/giphy.gif')
      .setFooter('You\'re late!')
    }
  })
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GuildChannel.overwritePermissions`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=overwritePermissions) and the [`setTimeout` function](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp):

```js
if (entNa.includes("Everyone got")) {
  const bapak = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle("THE EVENT IS OVER!")
    .setImage("https://media.giphy.com/media/l4Ki2obCyAQS5WhFe/giphy.gif")
    .setFooter("You're late!");
  message.channel.send(bapak);

  // lock the channel
  message.channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
      "SEND_MESSAGES": false,
    },
  );

  // unlock the channel after 5 seconds (5000 ms)
  setTimeout(() => {
    message.channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
      "SEND_MESSAGES": true,
    },
  );
  }, 5000);
}
```

Comment: omg sir thanks so much, very much, super duper much

Comment: Glad I could help :) Make sure to [mark my answer as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A,the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.) if it solved your problem.

Comment: btw sir, the problem is the bot will reset the permission, all the permission on that channel

Comment: Ah, then you should use [`updateOverwrite`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannel?scrollTo=updateOverwrite) instead. See my edited answer.